# laravel 7 edit old value not selected form

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-6, laravel-7

hello i use this code for select category in edit form and it is not work!
this line not work

```
<option value="{{$category->id}}" {{ old('parent')  ? 'selected' : '' }} >
```

and use this but two code not worked!

```
 {{ in_array($category->id ,$category->child()->pluck('id')->toArray()) ? 'selected': ''}}
```

my code is

```
 <option value="0"{{$category->parent == '0' ? 'selected': ''}}>دسته اصلی</option>
@foreach(\App\Category::all() as $category)
<option value="{{$category->id}}"  {{ in_array($category->id ,$category->child()->pluck('id')->toArray()) ? 'selected': ''}}>
 @if($category->parent== 0)
 {{$category->name}}
 @else
-- {{$category->name}}
 @endif
</option>
@endforeach
```

and my model category this

```
  public function child()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Category::class, 'parent', 'id');
}

public function get_parent()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Category::class,'id','parent');
}
```

Comment: Do you actually want `old('parent')==$category->id`?

Comment: i want get recived category that i selected in when create

Comment: i use this but it is not work  {{ in_array($category->id ,$category->child()->pluck('id')->toArray()) ? 'selected': ''}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You need to do it this way**

```
<option value="{{ $category->id }}" {{ old('parent') == $category->id ? 'selected' : '' }} >
```

**But suppose if you have all categories and a category with edit record also, means you have come to edit page with a single category and you want that to be selected by default then.**

```
<option value="{{ $category->id }}" @isset($cat) {{ $cat->id == $category->id ? 'selected' : '' }} @endisset >
```

In this case `$cat` is a single category for edit and `$category` is your looping through all categories in dropdown.

> UPDATED CODE

```
 <select name="parent" id="parent">
     <option value="0"{{$category->parent == '0' ? 'selected': ''}}>دسته اصلی</option>
     @foreach(\App\Category::all() as $category_loop)
        <option value="{{$category->id}}"
          @isset($category) {{ $category->parent == $category_loop->id ? 'selected' : '' }} @endisset>
          @if($category_loop->parent== 0)
             {{$category_loop->name}}
          @else
          -- {{$category_loop->name}}
          @endif
        </option>
     @endforeach
 </select>
```

Comment: Are you editing the records and you want that edit category should be selected on the edit page, right ?

Comment: https://www.mediafire.com/file/kydz5g9ovry96lk/edit.blade.php/file

Comment: this is the blade file, i am talking about edit method in controller ? show me just that edit code.

Comment: public function edit(Category $category)
    {
        return view('admin.categories.edit',compact('category'));
    }